# How to force TypeScript to recompile all files even if source unchanged?

Tags: typescript

I've been experimenting with different settings in my `tsconfig.json`.  As part of this, I want to re-compile all my TypeScript files to see how the emitted JavaScript differs with the new settings (e.g. changing the `module` option).

The underlying `.ts` files themselves haven't changed, however, and so calling `tsc` does nothing.

How can I tell `tsc` to recreate all the files even though it thinks it doesn't need to?

For reference, I'm invoking the TypeScript compiler like so:

```
node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build src/tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Have you tried `tsc --incremental false ...`?

Comment: It looks like I can't use that with the `--build` flag as I get `File /current/path/--incremental' does not exist (and likewise for `.../false`). If I remove `--build` then I get  `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '--incremental'.` which is odd because the option is mentioned in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html. My tsc version is 3.0.1. But I've found a solution now (see my answer). Thanks for your suggestion, though!

Comment: Apparently the `--incremental` option was added with TypeScript 3.4: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html That could be the reason why you are getting an error.

Comment: Aha, thanks for explaining, and for the original suggestion. I'm sure others who find this question will be able to make good use of it :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I discovered the answer - although `tsc` doesn't have a "top-level" force option, since I'm already using the `--build` option, I can pass `--force` to that:

```
node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build --force src/tsconfig.json
```

From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html):

> There are also some flags specific to `tsc -b`:
>   [...]
>
> `--force`: Act as if all projects are out of date

Answer (score 3):

As a follow to Sam's answer, in the specific case you have the incremental flag set to `true` (the default) you can also delete the `.tsbuildinfo` file created by Typescript. This contains metadata about what files are / are not up to date. Without this data, `tsc -b` will re-compile your entire project.

[Incremental flag docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#incremental)

Answer (score 0):

I use below this command to make always watching

```bash
node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build --force tsconfig.json --watch
```